# How to track link clicks from Twilio SMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hi Stack OverFlow community and Twilio Lovers.

I am a product manager for a fitness app, we are looking to send automated messages to our new users welcoming them to our app. We would like to include a link which the user clicks and then sends them to our app. Is there a way in Twilio to:

- Implement such a customised link sending the user to our app
- Count the number of link clicks
- Associate a link click with a phone number (and by extension user)

Thank you,

Cara

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio messaging API is a channel through which you can send messages, but it does not offer other things like the analytics you are looking for here. However, that is something you can build in yourself.

As a suggestion, [Firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) could work for you, especially if you are linking into an application. You create the link with an API call, the link can handle opening the app and will gather analytics on the usage too.